# Windows Service could not connect to WCF Service when installed on the same web server

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, windows-authentication

I have to provide the userPrincipalName if the windows service is installed on the same web server but I can remove the identity tag if the windows service is installed on any other machine. what could be the reason of such behaviour? 
NOTE: Application pool is running under custom domain account
Here is my Windows Service app.config settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITimerJobService">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://domain/TimerJobService.svc"
        binding = "wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration = "WSHttpBinding_ITimerJobService" contract="TimerJob.ITimerJobService" name= "WSHttpBinding_ITimerJobService">
        <identity>
            <userPrincipalName value="ApplicationPoolIdentity"/>
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your `bindingConfiguration` value doesn't match the name of the defined binding - you have "wsbindingname", and the name in the definition is "WSHttpBinding_ITimerJobService".

Comment: Sorry that mistake i made when i was posting the code. Now it looks fine but the behaviour is still the same. Any ideas???